# Why isn't /var/log/maillog written with sync option by default?

Tags: syslog

Some syslog implementations on linux (sysklogd, rsyslog) include the following line in their default configuration:

```
mail.*    -/var/log/maillog
```

As far as I know the dash sign means that it is not required to do sync() after a log message is written to this logfile.

Why is that and why should we handle maillog differently?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason: `/var/log/maillog` is usually so huge. Put a minus sign before this entry to avoid slow down the system (when syncing the file after every logging).

Comment: Well, probably, but I have log files that are way larger than maillog. I suspect a more historical reason in this case but I wasn't able to find it with google.

Comment: If losing some logs didn't hurt, prefix with a minus sign to gain some performance. I don't think there is a historical reason here.

Comment: @Downvoter: please leave a comment to let me know why.

Comment: @Zizzencs a maillog should neither carry critical information nor be security-related so it typically should be safe to buffer writes for it.